# How to control proper iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

my code/site is embedded into iframe. It's on the same domain so I can access parent document without problem.

The problem is that iframe in which my code resides is dynamically generated - every-time the site reloads it get a new ID and has no class.

So, I have this code:

```
$("iframe", window.parent.document).each(function () {
  var iFrame = this;

  if ($("#controlAddIn",iFrame)) {
    iFrame.css({"height": "29px", "padding-bottom": "12px"});
  }
});
```

And firefox console gives me this:

> TypeError: iFrame.css is not a function

What I want to achieve is to re-size iframe in which my code is to a fixed value + change padding.

What is wrong with my solution that firefox doesn't wan't to execute it?

Thank you.

Comment: use `var iFrame = $(this);`

Comment: instead iFrame.css try $(this).css...

Comment: @ss56 I'd like to set your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks.. but there is more good information in your accepted answer.. :) all the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `iFrame` is set to `this`. `.css` is a jQuery function and `this` is no jQuery object.
So you either have to make your `iFrame` a jQuery object by assigning `$(this)` to it, or use plain JavaScript to assign the styles to it.

```
$(this).css({"height": "29px", "padding-bottom": "12px"});
```

or

```
this.style.height = '29px';
this.style.paddingBottom = '12px';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ifram_id").css({"height": "29px", "padding-bottom": "12px"});


<iframe id="ifram_id" name="dynamicframe" src="javascript:'';" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;height: 116px;border: 2px solid rgb(0, 224, 255);"></iframe>
```